# how to keep up white spaces between words in iText5

Tags: itext

In my case, I read strings from a data base and then i want to make a PDF with **itext5**.

The string could be like this: **I like   oranges and potatoes**

If you can see between the words like and oranges there are 3 white spaces.

When i create a paragraph with this text in the resulting PDF i have the next text: **I like oranges and potatoes**.

The white spaces between like and oranges are lost.

Is it possible to keep up the White spaces?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your white space is in left `(" hello")` , the generated pdf will take that whitespace automatically.
for right side `("hello ")` replace white space with `"\u00a0"` .

```
String string="hello ";
string=string.replace(" ","\u00a0");
```